# Simple sql-merge

Tags: sql, merge, google-bigquery

I am usually happy using sql merge (using google bigquery with its version of sql but I think the question is generic). However, I have this one usecase I have not been able to solve with merge.

I have a source table s and a target table t. They both have a field called 'day'. I want to delete all the rows from t that contain a date which is featured in s. Then I want to insert all rows from s in t.

Not using merge, I can do it using two statements:

```
delete from t where day in (select day from s);
insert into t (select * from s);
```

However, I would like to do it as a single statement using merge.
My best effort is this

```
merge t
using s
on false
when not matched by target then
insert row
when not matched by source and t.day between
(select min(day) from s) and (select max(day) from s)
then delete
```

This works fine as long as the dates in s form one continous interval. However, for arbitrary dates it obviously deletes too much from t. I have tried

```
merge t
using s
on false
when not matched by target then
insert row
when not matched by source and t.day in
(select day from s)
```

but that final subquery is not allowed in bigquery. I get the error

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Correlated Subquery is unsupported in WHEN clause.
```

Can anyone help? This seems like a very simple operation, but I have simply been unable to write a proper merge statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's a suitable scenario to use merge. However it's very easy if you use UNION.

You basically select all rows in t which day doesn't appear in s and then append all rows of s.

```
select * from t where day not in (SELECT distinct(day) from s)
UNION ALL select * from s
```

Comment: Hey, this is a great solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, subqueries within a WHEN clause [are not supported for MERGE statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language#limitations) in BigQuery. There's an open [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927) with a [similar scenario](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927#comment9) and a [workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905927#comment14) that might be helpful to you.